# jQuery click event not bound to element in Firefox, works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I have the following HTML:

```
<a id="ajaxToggleHotkeys"  title="Toggle Hotkey Info" href="#" style="display: inline;"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i></a>
```

and the following jQuery/JS:

```
$('#ajaxToggleHotkeys').on('click', function(event) {
    toggleHotkeysDisplay ();
});
```

and yes, the JS code is in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

block.

This works beautifully in Chrome, but in Firefox the event doesn't fire. If I use the Firefox "Inspect Element" tool, I don't see an events at all bound to this element.

So for some reason the event isn't bound to the `#ajaxToggleHotkeys` element. I've been banging my head against this one for a few hours now and am at a total loss.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've no problem running your code on Firefox.

```js
$('#ajaxToggleHotkeys').on('click', function(event) {
    toggleHotkeysDisplay ();
});

function toggleHotkeysDisplay(){
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("I'm here")
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="ajaxToggleHotkeys"  title="Toggle Hotkey Info" href="#" style="display: inline;"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i> TEST</a>
```

---

Try starting Firefox in Safe Mode and check if the error persists.

> You can start Firefox in Safe Mode in two ways
>
> ```
> Hold the SHIFT key while double clicking the Firefox icon in your desktop
> Press the Windows key + R (open the Run command) and type firefox -safe-mode
> ```

Comment: Thanks for testing this. Safe mode makes no difference, it must be some interaction with the rest of my JS code somewhere. The odd thing is that it works in chrome.

Comment: I guess I cannot help you with that...Be sure that your code works on FF. GL !

Comment: Upon further investigation it seems that I have a general problem in Firefox with click events. None of my click events (all bound via the "on" method) work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any Antivirus monitoring FF ?

Comment: No, I'm on Linux, no Antivirus installed/necessary.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is included correctly ? try including a local copy of the jQuery, it may have been cached incorrectly by FF.

Comment: Found the problem. The "ajaxToggleHokeys" ID tag seemed to have an invisible control character in it. Once type that tag in again, everything started to work. Thanks for the help.